# Best IDE for developing spring based application

Tags: spring, ide

I have to develop web based application on spring currently i am using eclipse.

i have installed plug-in for spring development is there any better options to choose open source IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choice of IDE is always a personal preference.

Mine is to use Intellij IDEA ultimate. Obivouslly this invokes you paying for a license but it is in my opinion a very well thought out IDE for all aspects of java development and includes great support for spring.

For an opensource alternative try the [springsource tool suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) it's basically a canned version of ecplise with all the plugins installed.

Comment: @Davis I need opensource IDE currently i can not pay for any kind of license it will be great if u suggest any opensource IDE

Comment: Attempted to add a link to STs damn hard todo while editing on an iPhone

Comment: Well you can post it as a answer to this question

Comment: well i got it how do i do thanks for your support

Comment: No worries.. Don't be shy with the up vote :-)